# complex JOIN Query, all DISTINCT from a table with latest DATE attribute from another TABLE

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have table named Business Entities "BE" and another named Questionnaire "Q", there is another table named which holds their Relationship Name "QBE"

**Table: BE**

```
| BE_ID | Region | Name | Description | 
| 1     | A      | kl   | ssss        |
| 2     | A      | dds  | s saals     |
| 3     | B      | wf   | ksd ks skd  |
| 4     | B      | dsc  | sam sd  ;   |
```

**Table: Q**

```
| Q_ID  | Name  | CreationDate  |
| 1     | sce   | 2014-01-01    |
| 2     | wcd   | 2014-02-01    |
```

**Table: QBE**

```
| QBE_ID | BE_ID | Q_ID |
| 1      | 1     | 1    |
| 2      | 1     | 2    |
| 3      | 2     | 2    |
```

now I want to select all the distinct Region from **BE** where CreationDate of **Q** is latest.

I am working on these lines. First JOIN

```
| QBE_ID | BE_ID | Q_ID | Region | Name | Name  | CreationDate  | 
| 1      | 1     | 1    | A      | kl   | sce   | 2014-01-01    |
| 2      | 1     | 2    | A      | dds  | sce   | 2014-02-01    |
| 3      | 2     | 2    | B      | wf   | wcd   | 2014-02-01    |
```

then from this I want to select

```
| QBE_ID | BE_ID | Q_ID | Region | Name | Name  | CreationDate  | 
| 2      | 1     | 2    | A      | dds  | sce   | 2014-02-01    |
| 3      | 2     | 2    | B      | wf   | wcd   | 2014-02-01    |
```

for all Regions "A" Q_ID "2" had the Questionaire with latest CreationDate so, then for All Regions "B" then for all others.

So far here is what I have been doing, don't read it its complex just tell me how to do it.

```
SELECT BE.NAME00, QUES.ANSWER, QUES.DESCRIPTION, QT.CREATION_DATE
  FROM OPAGES.RV_ENTITY AS BE,
      OPAGES.RT__ENTITY_QUESTIONNAIRE AS EN_QT,
      OPAGES.RV_QUESTIONNAIRE AS QT,
      OPAGES.RT__QUESTIONNAIRE_QSECTION AS QT_SEC,
      OPAGES.RT__QSECTION_QUEST AS SEC_QUES, OPAGES.RT_QUEST AS QUES
  WHERE BE.ENTITY_ID = EN_QT.ENTITY_ID AND EN_QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID =
QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
    AND QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID = QT_SEC.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
    AND QT_SEC.QSECTION_ID = SEC_QUES.QSECTION_ID
    AND SEC_QUES.QUEST_ID = QUES.QUEST_ID
    AND QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID= (SELECT QT_SEC.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
  FROM OPAGES.RT__QUESTIONNAIRE_QSECTION AS QT_SEC,
      OPAGES.RV_QUESTIONNAIRE AS QT
  WHERE QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID = QT_SEC.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
  GROUP BY QT_SEC.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID, QT.CREATION_DATE
  ORDER BY QT.CREATION_DATE DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
)
  GROUP BY QT.CREATION_DATE, QUES.DESCRIPTION, QUES.ANSWER, BE.NAME00
```

I am thinking something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE (User, Date) IN
  ( SELECT User, MAX(Date) FROM MyTable GROUP BY User)
```

just cant materialize it

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: IBM DB2 and I'm experimenting with query using IBM DataStudio

Comment: Surely db2 allows explit joins, use them. Implicit joins are a very bad SQL antipattern. They are far more prone to errorand harder to maintain.

Comment: I will use explicit joins, that is not the problem, the problem is the approach, i cant formulate an approach, p.s. this query is old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT 
       EN_QT.ENTITY_ID, 
       QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID, 
       QT.CREATION_DATE AS CREATION_DATE
       FROM 
       OPAGES.RV_QUESTIONNAIRE AS QT,
       OPAGES.RT__ENTITY_QUESTIONNAIRE AS EN_QT
       WHERE EN_QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID = QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
       GROUP BY 
       EN_QT.ENTITY_ID, 
       QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID, 
       QT.CREATION_DATE
     )
       WHERE (ENTITY_ID, CREATION_DATE) 
       IN (
            SELECT 
            KILL.ENTITY_ID,
            MAX(KILL.CREATION_DATE)
            FROM (
                  SELECT 
                  EN_QT.ENTITY_ID,
                  QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID,
                  QT.CREATION_DATE AS CREATION_DATE
                  FROM 
                  OPAGES.RV_QUESTIONNAIRE AS QT,
                  OPAGES.RT__ENTITY_QUESTIONNAIRE AS EN_QT
                  WHERE 
                  EN_QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID =QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID

                  GROUP BY 
                  EN_QT.ENTITY_ID,
                  QT.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID,
                  QT.CREATION_DATE
                 ) AS KILL
                  GROUP BY KILL.ENTITY_ID
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Generating a row number for each BE_ID, Q_ID combination based on the creation date, The outer select is taking the latest value for each of these sets BE_ID,Q_ID.

```
SELECT * from
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by BE.BE_ID, Q.Q_ID order by Q.CreationDate desc) as seq
    FROM BE
    INNER JOIN QBE
    ON BE.BE_ID = QBE.QBE_ID
    INNER JOIN Q
    ON Q.Q_ID = QBE.Q_ID
) T
WHERE T.seq =1
```

Comment: Please explain and format your code. Code only answers are not so helpful especially for beginners.

Comment: @Pred, Thanks, added the comments and formatted the code.